# HTML/CSS: Show full size image on click

Tags: html, css

I have a text + image side by side, and I want a function where the user can click on the image to make it bigger. I'm new to HTML/CSS so I was wondering how I can approach this. Thanks! (demo -> https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/6634/)

Is there any way to do this with pure HTML/CSS and no javascript?

The ones I found have been telling me to use javascript such as:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function showImage(imgName) {
            document.getElementById('largeImg').src = imgName;
            showLargeImagePanel();
            unselectAll();
        }
        function showLargeImagePanel() {
            document.getElementById('largeImgPanel').style.visibility = 'visible';
        }
        function unselectAll() {
            if(document.selection) document.selection.empty();
            if(window.getSelection) window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
        }
        function hideMe(obj) {
            obj.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
        </script>
```

Is there a simpler way to do this in HTML/CSS?

Comment: There is no way to only use HTML/CSS to enlarge your image. You could create another CSS class selector and use JS or JQuery to change the image's class to alter its size.

Comment: Yep, can't be simpler than Javascript/Jquery :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a CSS pseudo-class to change the styling when, for example, the mouse is over the image:

```
img:hover {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

Generally, though, to add interactivity to your web pages, you will have to become acquainted with JavaScript. I don't know of any way to toggle a state (e.g. "zoomed-in") without the use of JavaScript.

You can think of the HTML as defining the content, the CSS as defining how it looks, and the JavaScript as defining how it behaves.

Comment: how can i make it pop up another window when hovering?

Comment: @Ave create a popup and set the `opacity` to `0` and use `:hover` to change the value of the `opacity `

Comment: If you just want to open the full size image in a new window, you can do that on click by wrapping it in a link with the target `_blank`. For example: `<a href="/image.png" target="_blank"><img src="/image.png" class="thumbnail"></a>`